# How to enable CDI inject in web service (jaxrs/jersey) on java se running grizzly?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, cdi, grizzly

How do I allow CDI injection of resources into restful web service resources?  I am running on standard java using weld 2 (cdi), jersey (jaxrs), and grizzly (web server).  Here is my simple web resource:

```java
import training.student.StudentRepository;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("student")
public class StudentWebResource {
  @Inject
  private StudentRepository studentRepository;  

  @GET
  @Path("count")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Integer getCount() {
    return studentRepository.studentCount();
  }
}
```

And here is how I've got weld starting my simple web server:

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    startCdiApplication();
  }

  public static void startCdiApplication() throws Exception {
    Weld weld = new Weld();
    try {
      WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
      Application application = container.instance().select(WebServer.class).get();
      application.run();
    } 
    finally {
      weld.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

And the code that I suspect will need to be modified to inform jersey to use weld for CDI inject resolution:

```
...
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class WebServer implements Application {

  /*
   * startup the grizzly http server to make available the restful web services
   */
  private void startWebServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig().packages("training.webservice").register(new JacksonFeature());
    final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(getBaseUri(), resourceConfig);
    server.start();
    Thread.currentThread().join();
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    startWebServer();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After seeing [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0), I implemented the following solution.  Not sure if it is the best route to take, but it worked.

I created an hk2 Binder and registered the Binder:

```java
public class WebServiceBinder extends AbstractBinder {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    BeanManager bm = getBeanManager();
    bind(getBean(bm, StudentRepository.class))
        .to(StudentRepository.class);
  }

  private BeanManager getBeanManager() {
    // is there a better way to get the bean manager?
    return new Weld().getBeanManager();
  }

  private <T> T getBean(BeanManager bm, Class<T> clazz) {
    Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) bm.getBeans(clazz).iterator().next();
    CreationalContext<T> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
    return (T) bm.getReference(bean, clazz, ctx); 
  }
}
```

Then modified the ResourceConfig instantiation from above to:

```
final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig()
    .packages("training.webservice")
    .register(new JacksonFeature())
    .register(new WebServiceBinder());
```

Comment: That will work, but you're better off to use the SE integration of the CDI implementation you're using (it's not in the spec, but they all do it).

Comment: Do you mean instead of initializing CDI via the Weld object I should be using (in the case of Weld) the StartMain.main static method and then have a `public void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized event)`? or are you referring to the hk2 CDI implementation?

Comment: Either one will work. If you're in an OSGI environment and need the separation the hk2 or weld-osgi project would work.

Comment: Could you make it work using the ContainerInitialized approach?

Comment: BTW, a better way to obtain the BeanManager is CDI.current().getBeanManager().

Comment: @javabeats Thanks for the information... and no, I didn't end up observing the `ContainerInitialized` event.

Comment: I used your approach too (save for the part where we get the BeanManager reference), and it worked. However, like you, I feel this is not optimal. I searched everywhere, and I couldn't find a solution to integrate Grizzly's H2K with a CDI implementation. Too bad.

Comment: OMG, you guys saved my life. Using the bean manager for the injection binding is the only way I got my @ApplicationScoped CDI beans (Weld 2.0.4) injected in my JAX-RS resource class (Jersey 2.3.1). But I wonder why it is so complicated getting CDI and JAX-RS work together in a servlet container?

Comment: Warning. This answer is outdated since Jersey 2.

Answer (score 6):

The selected answer dates from a while back. It is not practical to declare every binding in a custom HK2 binder.
I just had to add one dependency. Even though it was designed for Glassfish it fits perfectly into other containers. I'm using Tomcat / Grizzly.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is an example with JerseyTest (same principle if you run it from a main method). I just had to declare a dependency on weld-se and declare a Weld container before instantiating my resources - as you also did - and it works out of the box.

```
public class GrizzlyTest extends JerseyTest {
    private Weld weld;
    private WeldContainer container;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        weld = new Weld();
        container = weld.initialize();
        return new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(target("myresource").request().get(String.class));
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        weld.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: True that accepted answer is outdated since when Jersey 2 has seen the daylight but ... your code snippet is also flawed: `new Weld()` should be used to start Weld container in a standalone env, not inside the servlet container. Register Weld servlet listener instead.

Comment: Could you then post a working example registering a Weld servlet listener on a JerseyTest config ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your code snippet is perfectly ok, as it is just a test class. But OP asked about enabling CDI (Weld) in a servlet container.

Answer (score 2):

Since at least Weld 2.2.0.Final there is no need to mess up with HK2 Binder.

As official Weld [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_tomcat) states you just need to register `org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener`. Code snipped from doc:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException, LifecycleException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/", new File("src/main/resources").getAbsolutePath());

        Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "hello", HelloWorldServlet.class.getName());
        ctx.addServletMapping("/*", "hello");

        ctx.addApplicationListener(Listener.class.getName());

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

    public static class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Inject
        private BeanManager manager;

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().append("Hello from " + manager);
        }
    }
}
```

Above servlet listener manages the **whole lifecycle** of the Weld container. So there is no need to:

```
 Weld weld = new Weld();
 WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
```

---

**UPDATE**
As @EdMelo pointed out, Grizzly HTTP server is not a fully compliant Servlet container. I didn't know this, thanks for this hint. So I'm not sure, if my answer still applies here.