# Injection in Webservice return NPE

Tags: web-services, cdi

Trying to inject a bean inside a webservice I always get NullPointerException.

**See:**

```java
package br.com.ewatt.webservice;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

import br.com.ewatt.bo.MedidorBOImpl;

@Path("")
public class MedidorWs {

    @Inject
    private MedidorBOImpl medidorBO;

    @Path("/receber_corrente/{mac}/{corrente}")
    @GET
    public void receberCorrente(@PathParam("mac") String mac,
            @PathParam("corrente") double corrente) {
        medidorBO.registrarConsumo(mac, corrente);

    }

    public MedidorBOImpl getMedidorBO() {
        return medidorBO;
    }

    public void setMedidorBO(MedidorBOImpl medidorBO) {
        this.medidorBO = medidorBO;
    }

}
```

I tried use @Named and @ApplicationScoped in MedidorWs class but didn't work, the attribute medidorBO is always null.

Comment: What container are you using, including version? You have a `beans.xml` in your `WEB-INF` directory?

Comment: i'm using tomcat, and yes i have beans.xml in web-inf. Others injections works normally, just in webservice dont work.

Comment: Please provide more info.  CDI implementation? JAX-RS impl?  And don't forget versions.

Comment: I'm using CDI Weld 2.3.0 Final + Jersey 1.8

Comment: My guess is that jersey support for CDI isn't being activated for any number of reasons.  If you can update jersey to a reasonably recent version, this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224270/how-to-enable-cdi-inject-in-web-service-jaxrs-jersey-on-java-se-running-grizzl 4 year old versions of libraries are just asking for trouble.

Comment: I tried update the jersey to 1.8 but didnt work