# How to add Guice to Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, guice, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I use embedded server Grizzly, so I do not have web.xml.
How to add google Guice to Jersey?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
    URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages("some.package");
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config, false);
    server.start();
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080911/how-to-use-jersey-2-0-guice-on-grizzly

Comment: @tim-yates It is not duplicate, because they use web.xml and I am not

Comment: the solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080911/how-to-use-jersey-2-0-guice-on-grizzly/39412650#answer-39412650