# Jersey 2: how to bind injection classes without package scanning?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

Originally I did include my classes manually by doing this

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(RestServlet.class);
        classes.add(RestService.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Then I found [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0) in order to be able to inject RestService in RestServlet I need to use a ResourceConfig binder instead.

```
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestApplication() {
        register(new RestBinder());
        packages(true, "");
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to use ResourceConfig without defining a package and bind it manually for each injection class?

PS I also don't understand how to make sure all package scanning is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ResourceConfig#register()` method for this purpose as well:

```
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestApplication() {
        register(new RestBinder());

        register(RestServlet.class);
        register(RestService.class);
    }
}
```

With this kind of registration your packages are not scanned for any other additional resources or providers. Providers discoverable via `META-INF/services` are still registered into your application. You can turn this feature off via, for server and client,  `jersey.config.disableMetainfServicesLookup` property or, for server only, `jersey.config.disableMetainfServicesLookup.server` (you can find this and other properties in [ServerProperties](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html) class):

```
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestApplication() {
        register(new RestBinder());

        register(RestServlet.class);
        register(RestService.class);

        property(ServerProperties.METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works thanks :) Just want to add that I did not need to `register(RestService.class);` for `@Inject RestService restService;` to work in `RestServlet`. `register(new RestBinder());` and `register(RestServlet.class);` was enough.