# CDI JAX-RS BeanValidation in Glassfish4

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, bean-validation, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have a simple JAX-RS InvoiceResource with an injected bean:

```java
@Path("invoices")
public class InvoiceResource {

    @Inject
    private InvoiceStore invoiceDao;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(@Context UriInfo uri, InvoiceDto invoiceDto) {
```

I wanted to add validation of the InvoiceDto I'm recieving, so I added an annotation:

```java
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response create(@Context UriInfo uri, @Valid InvoiceDto invoiceDto) {
```

Now it seems that this breaks CDI. I start to get the following error:

```java
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=InvoiceStore,parent=InvoiceResource,qualifiers={})
```

I was expecting a validation exception istead. What am I doing wrong? I'm using glassfish 4 web profile, and if I understood correctly applying validation to params is part of Java EE 7 CDI 1.1 spec.

Comment: Is there a CDI bean of type `InvoiceStore`? This doesn't really seem related to Bean Validation.

Comment: @Gunnar yes, without the validation it does work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Glassfish 4.0.0 implementation. I've found this article which describes what's happening and gives a workaround:

http://www.rogerdelafuente.com/glassfish-4-jax-rs-cdi-bean-validation-bug/

Thanks to everybody who stepped in, it helped me a lot to understand the HK2 thing. Finally it should work without any hacks, making the app portable, once this bug is fixed.

Comment: oh its not a glass fish bug

Comment: It is. Replacing the jar as the article said removed the problem. You can try with the example in the article.

Comment: Mine is GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89), but I'm running it from maven with cargo, (cargo:run), which is downloading the appserver from http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.0/release/glassfish-4.0-web.zip

Answer (score 1):

Its clear form error that its not Bean validation issue but its DI issue . The actual problem is that the  Jersey JAX-RS implementation uses the HK2 DI framework, HK2 is not simply aware of CDI beans. You have to make CDI beans available for the HK2 injection bindings. you can follow [this post](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Custom-providers-in-Jersey-2-td7580699.html)

[HK2 Glassfish Integration](https://hk2.java.net/integration.html)

```
HK2 can be used in GlassFish applications. Every deployed GlassFish application has
a unique ServiceLocator associated with it that can be looked up with 
  JNDI name java:app/hk2/ServiceLocator.
```

Same issue [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0)

Simple solution is that if you want to use weld CDI then you need to just put empty beans.xml file in web-inf.

Comment: Ok, so I had the beans.xml in the wrong place and think I've been using WELD all this time. Now, I moved it to WEB-INF.
Now I still get the error, and did look at the other question you mentioned, but this seems like a hack for Glassfish. Will this be portable to other AppServer? What's the JEE7 standar way?

Comment: To be clear: Jersey's implementation of JAX-RS uses its own DI Framework, and I need to manually glue the standard CDI to it. But shouldn't this be a task of the AppServer? What happens if I change to another AppServer which uses other JAX-RS implementation?

Comment: for CDI beans.xml is necessary what ever you are using RI. either its weld or openwebbean