# Inject a singleton in an ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, cdi

I have an ExceptionMapper defined as following

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
   @Inject
   private Manager myManager;

   @Override
   public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
      // My implementation
   }
}
```

Deploying this code on glassfish 4 results with exception:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
There was no object available for injection at
Injectee(requiredType=Manager,parent=MyExceptionMapper,qualifiers {}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,955636053)
```

When I use @Context instead of @Inject I do not see the exception but myManager is null
I tried making MyManager as @ManagedBean, @Singleton or an EJB (Stateless, Singleton) and non works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the suggested solution is not quite practical since I have to bind all my CDI beans that I need to inject  inside MyExceptionMapper (and there dependencies)

Comment: where do you deploy? glassfish-4?

Comment: Are you create beans.xml? Inject annotation doesn't work with out it.

Comment: I have beans.xml but I do not list my beans in it, and inject works when I inject one ManagedBean inside another ManagedBean

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @Fedy2 It is working on glassfish 4.1.1

Comment: @hmashlah If you found a solution please post it and mark it as accepted. FWIW, CDI injection in Wildfly 8 works just fine in JAX-RS providers just by adding a scope annotation. For me, Dependent works.

Answer (score 0):

In JEE6 (with glassfish 3) you have to add

```
@javax.annotation.ManagedBean
```

to the provider implementation. Possibly this works also for Glassfish 4

As far as I know, this issues comes from the following. CDI is not in place to manage the dependencies of restful services and providers by default. But when adding @ManagedBean you enable CDI to create the instance.

Here is an [example](http://coders-kitchen.com/2013/03/29/tutorial-how-to-use-jax-rs-and-cdi-together/%20example) where I introduced CDI to a restful service using jersey.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but adding ManagedBean to the ExceptionMapper did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the updates regarding this issue here https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2393

Answer (score 0):

You could use OmniFaces [`Beans`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Beans) to get a CDI managed bean instance in your `ExceptionMapper`:

```
Beans.getInstance(Bean.class)
```

I'm using this with `@javax.ejb.Stateless` beans containing `@javax.persistence.PersistenceContext`.