# No object available for injection

Tags: glassfish, jersey, cdi, restful-architecture

I'm having serious problems by trying to run [this](https://github.com/m-reza-rahman/javaee-mobile/tree/master/javaee-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/javaee/mobile/server/todo) template project for setting up RESTful web services. I constantly get the exception

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=ToDoService,parent=ToDoResource,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,383253211)
```

I've read similar posts and most of them suggest using an AbstractBinder. I tried to do so by inserting a class

```
public class MyBinder extends AbstractBinder {
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(DefaultToDoService.class).to(ToDoService.class);
}
}
```

but now I don't know where to register it. I tried to do so inside the RestConfiguration class which extends Application, but the register method does not exist there... the Jersey doc does not seem very clear on that subject. If you could give me a little help that could save me a lot of time!

Comment: I believe you simply add it to the class set in `getClasses` in `RestConfiguration`.

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed...

Comment: well I solved it by just calling the DefaultToDoService with a standard "new" statement, instead of injecting it. Honestly, I find this whole injection mechanism quite buggy and confusing, and pretty useless for relatively small applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0)