# Adding custom headers in Jersey Filters isn't working

Tags: java, filter, jersey, request, dropwizard

I am new to DropWizard framework and Jersey in general. So I could be completely off the track with what I am trying to accomplish here.

I am running into an issue where the parameters I add to my request header through a pre-matching Request filter are not reaching the custom provider for my AuthCredentials object.  I am trying to provide a AuthCredentials object for every resource that requires auth from the header parameters . Since one of the services I am going to rely on for providing auth headers isn't ready yet i am faking them out by adding them in the pre-matching request filter myself.

Here's my code

```
 @PreMatching
 @Provider
 class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add("param1", "value1");
   }
}


class MyAuthCredentialsFactory implements Factory<AuthCredentials>{
     @Inject
     public MyAuthCredentialsFactory(HttpServletRequest request){
          System.out.println("Param1 header value = " + request.getHeader("param1")); // <---This prints null
     }
}
```

I am registering these classes in my applications' run method in drop wizard framework as shown below.

```
@Override
    public void run(ServerConfigType configuration,
                    Environment environment) {
        environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
               @Override
               protected void configure() {
                  bindFactory(MyAuthCredentialsFactory.class).to(AuthCredentials.class).in(RequestScoped.class);               
               }
    });
    environment.jersey().register(MyFilter.class);
```

My resource uses auth credentials like this

```
@Path("/pathtomyresource")
public class MyApi {
    @Inject AuthCredentials authCredentials;
}
```

I am using DropWizard 0.8.3, and Jackson 2.5.3.

When I print the value of the param1 from the header I am getting a null. I looked at the HttpServletRequest's header names in the debugger, and didn't find the param1 in there which explains why the value is null.  I did a lot of research on the internet on this and found that it should work but isn't working for me. At this point I am puzzled and I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpServletRequest` and `ContainerRequestContext` are not the same thing, and setting something in the latter will not result in it being put in the former. You can inject `ContainerRequestContext` into the `Factory` though, and just get the property from there

```
 @Inject
 public MyAuthCredentialsFactory(ContainerRequestContext request){
 }
```

Personally what I just do, when I need to access the request context, is instead of implementing `Factory`, I just extend [`AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory.java) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30871950/2587435). Then you can just call `getContainerRequest()`, to get the `ContainerRequest` (which is actually the same `ContainerRequestContext`.

```
class MyAuthCredentialsFactory 
        extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<AuthCredentials> {
    @Override
    public AuthCrendials provide() {
        ContainerRequest request = getContainerRequest();
        String header = request.getHeaderString(...);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, instead of setting a header, you could set an arbitrary property on the `ContainerRequestContext` with `setProperty(key, value)`, then in the factory just get it with `getProperty(key)`

Comment: I injected my ContainerRequest in the factory since I have my own constructor for it. Used the setProperty instead of headers (though headers could have worked as well). Thanks peeskillet!