# Accessing JWT token payload variable/object in Resource method from filter

Tags: jersey, jwt

I have a filter for token validation and I am using JWT token for authentication and authorization.

Suppose I am passing user_id in the JWT token payload and I want this user_id to be available for all my resource methods that will pass my filter so that I can do query on the basis of user_id in my resource method.

Is this possible to do so?

Or how can I pass this user_id as a parameter to my resource methods from my filter ?

And whether it is a good practice to do so ?

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException, ConnectException {

        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();

        UserModel user = new UserModel();
        Claims claim =null;
        String temp=null;
        requestContext.setProperty("before","before");
      if (uriInfo.getPath().equals("profile")) {  

        String authorizationHeader = 
            requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // Check if the HTTP Authorization header is present and formatted correctly 
        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
        }

        // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
        String tokens = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

        try {
            claim = user.validateToken(tokens);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AuthorizationRequestFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        requestContext.setProperty("id",claim.getId());
        requestContext.setProperty("hello","hello");

      }
}
```

**I am able to get the value for "before" variable in my resource method.
but I am getting null for "hello" and "id". I want to get the value "id" in my resource method.**

Thanks

Comment: What Jersey version?

Comment: I am using jersey version 2.22

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject an object into jersey request context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665744/how-to-inject-an-object-into-jersey-request-context)

Comment: I have edited my question and written my filter.
I am not getting the value which I wanted in my resource.

Comment: Thanks for the link it has given me idea.
What is the problem in my filter?
I am not getting the value for "id".

Comment: you could show your resource and how do you try to get the property

Comment: Resolved ! . The problem was with my path.
How can I convert this filter to Namebinding filter.In which file I should add these lines.
@NameBinding