# Support only a limited number of languages

Tags: java, jersey, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0, http-accept-language

My API uses Jersey 2, and now I want to support internationalization. I understand my client should specify the `Accept-Language` parameter, but I want to understand how to handle it properly.

Let's assume that my API should handle only `FRENCH` and `ENGLISH` languages. I know I can retrieve the **preferred** locale with the following code:

```
@GET
@Path("a-path")
public Response doSomething(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Locale locale = request.getLocale();
    // ...
}
```

The problem is when the **preferred** locale isn't supported by my API. Let's say that my client send me `Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7`, according to [w3c](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4), it basically means: `"I prefer Danish, but will accept British English and other types of English."`. Since the *preferred* locale only return the most expected locale, is there a way to select the first supported language by my API? I would like to handle it in one place (i.e. in `Filters`) and not in every resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One to get the locales is to use [`HttpHeaders#getAcceptableLanguages()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getAcceptableLanguages--).

> Get a list of languages that are acceptable for the response.
>
> If no acceptable languages are specified, a read-only list containing a single wildcard Locale instance (with language field set to "*") is returned.
>
> **Returns:**
> a read-only list of acceptable languages sorted according to their q-value, with highest preference first.

You can inject `HttpHeaders` pretty much anywhere, using `@Context`

```
public Response doSomething(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    List<Locale> langs = headers.getAcceptableLanguages();
```

If you wanted to get the list in a [filter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9678), you can also get the list list of locales from the [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html)

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throw .. {
    List<Locales> langs = requestContext.getAcceptableLanguages();
}
```

If you wanted to use the `Locale` in the resource method, but didn't want to do all the locale "resolving" in the method, you can use some dependency injection, and create a `Factory`, where you can inject he `HttpHeaders` and resolve the locale there

**See Also:** [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16216759/2587435)

Below is a complete test case example using a combination of last two points I mentioned about using a filter and dependency injection along a `Factory`, so that you can just inject the resolved `Locale` into the resource method. The example uses a dummy locale resolver that only allows english. After we resolve the locale, we set it into a request context property, and retrieve from inside the `Factory` so that we can inject it into the resource method

```
@GET
public String get(@Context Locale locale) {
   return locale.toString();
}
```

**See Also:** [How to inject an object into jersey request context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27665744/2587435)

Let me know if there is anything else you would like me to explain about the example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Stack Overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/q/36871274/2587435
 * 
 * Run this like any other JUnit test. Only one required test dependency:
 * 
 *  <dependency>
 *      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
 *      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 *  </dependency>
 *
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class AcceptLanguageTest extends JerseyTest {
    
    @Path("language")
    public static class TestResource {
       
        @GET
        public String get(@Context Locale locale) {
           return locale.toString();
        }
    }
    
    public static interface LocaleResolver {
        Locale resolveLocale(List<Locale> locales);
    }
    
    // Note: if you look in the javadoc for getAcceptableLanguages()
    // you will notice that it says if there is not acceptable language
    // specified, that there is a default single wildcard (*) locale.
    // So this implementation sucks, as it doesn't check for that.
    // You will want to make sure to do so!
    public static class DefaultLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {
        
        @Override
        public Locale resolveLocale(List<Locale> locales) {
            if (locales.contains(Locale.ENGLISH)) {
                return Locale.ENGLISH;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    @Provider
    @PreMatching
    public static class LocaleResolverFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
        
        static final String LOCALE_PROPERTY = "LocaleResolverFilter.localProperty";
        
        @Inject
        private LocaleResolver localeResolver;
        
        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
            List<Locale> locales = context.getAcceptableLanguages();
            Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(locales);
            if (locale == null) {
                context.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).build());
                return;
            }
            context.setProperty(LOCALE_PROPERTY, locale);
        }
    }
    
    public static class LocaleFactory implements Factory<Locale> {
        
        @Context
        private ContainerRequestContext context;

        @Override
        public Locale provide() {
            return (Locale) context.getProperty(LocaleResolverFilter.LOCALE_PROPERTY);
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(Locale l) {} 
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                .register(LocaleResolverFilter.class)
                .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                    @Override
                    protected void configure() {
                        bindFactory(LocaleFactory.class)
                                .to(Locale.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
                        bind(DefaultLocaleResolver.class)
                                .to(LocaleResolver.class).in(Singleton.class);
                    }
                })
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnEnglish() {
        final String accept = "da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7";
        final Response response = target("language").request()
                .acceptLanguage(accept)
                .get();
        assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class), is("en"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnNotAcceptable() {
        final String accept = "da";
        final Response response = target("language").request()
                .acceptLanguage(accept)
                .get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.getStatusCode()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JAX-RS API allows you to select a Locale with the Request.selectVariant(List) method.

Try the following code in either the REST handler or a CDI bean :

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Variant;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;

    @Context
    private Request req;

    private Locale getResponseLocale(boolean throwIfNoneMatch) throws NotAcceptableException{
        // Put your supported languages here
        List<Variant> langVariants = Variant.languages(
                new Locale("da"), 
                new Locale("en-gb"), 
                Locale.getDefault()).build();

        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        Variant selectVariant = this.req.selectVariant(langVariants);
        if (selectVariant != null) {
            locale = selectVariant.getLanguage();
        } else if (throwIfNoneMatch) {
            throw new NotAcceptableException(Response.notAcceptable(langVariants).build());
        }

        return locale;
    }
```

See also [The Java EE Tutorial : Runtime Content Negotiation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced006.htm).