# Jersey 2.x @Context / Dependency Injection in Scala

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, jersey, dropwizard

What I'm trying to do is make a custom jersey `@Context` for my methods, exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665744/how-to-inject-an-object-into-jersey-request-context), but in Scala.

Java way from the above post:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jetty.plugin.test.domain.MyObject;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;

public class MyObjectFactory implements Factory<MyObject> {

    private final ContainerRequestContext context;

    @Inject
    public MyObjectFactory(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject provide() {
        return (MyObject)context.getProperty("myObject");
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(MyObject t) {}  
}
```

Attempting the Scala way:

```
class MyObjFactory(ctr: ContainerRequestContext) extends Factory[MyObj] {
  private final val context: ContainerRequestContext = ctr

  override def provide(): MyObj = context.getProperty("customObj").asInstanceOf[MyObj]

  override def dispose(obj: MyObj): Unit = { }
}
```

The problem here is I don't know where to put the `@Inject` annotation.  My limited understanding of Scala is that everything in the class declaration is a constructor block, so I can't use `@Inject` to annotate the `MyObjectFactory` constructor method like in Java.

Am I just going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations goes with the constructor:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

class MyObjFactory @Inject()(ctr: ContainerRequestContext) extends Factory[MyObj] {

  private final val context: ContainerRequestContext = ctr

  override def provide(): MyObj = context.getProperty("customObj").asInstanceOf[MyObj]

  override def dispose(obj: MyObj): Unit = {}

}
```