# Injecting custom objects into the Request Bean

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

In my JAX-RS, Jersey application, I need to include a custom check before any API is invoked before the all the request to be processed.  The best approach is to use a JAX-RS filter.  To do this custom check, I need to do a database hit, check a few things etc.  The results from the database hit, would be useful to code path so I would like to pass them on. Rather than have the rest of code path have to make another B hit.  I see I can inject lots of thins using the @Context annotation.  Is there anyway I can extend this to get JAX-RS / Jersey to inject some custom objects?

Thanks

Comment: Would [Jersey Dependency Injection Docs](https://riptutorial.com/jersey/example/23632/basic-dependency-injection-using-jersey-s-hk2) help you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666797/2587435