# Correct CDI annotations with Jersey/Glassfish

Tags: java, dependency-injection, glassfish, jersey, cdi

Since I'm struggling on documentation about CDI, I hope this question could become a useful resource for the correct CDI annotations to use in Jersey/Glassfish.

Say we have an application `BookStore`:

```
package my.bookstore;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/bookstore")
public class BookStore extends ResourceConfig {
    public BookStore() {
        this.packages("my.bookstore.resource");
    }
}
```

We want to make `Book` entities accessible via a RESTful service:

```
package my.bookstore.entity;

public class Book {
    public String isbn;
    public String title;
    public String author;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, String author) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

So we need a `DAO` to access the datastore:

```
package my.bookstore.dao;

import my.bookstore.entity.Book;
import java.util.List;

public interface BookDAO {
    public List<Book> getAllBooks();
}
```

And its implementation:

```
package my.bookstore.dao;

import my.bookstore.entity.Book;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DefaultBookDAO implements BookDAO {
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Book("1234", "Awesome Book", "Some Author"));
        return bookList;
     }
}
```

Then I want to inject the `DefaultBookDAO` into the RESTful service:

```
package my.bookstore.resource;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/books")
public class BookResource {

   @Inject
   BookDAO dao;

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public List<Book> getBooks() {
       return this.dao.getAllBooks();
   }
}
```

Now, when deploying the application I get:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type BookDAO with qualifiers @Default
```

since I need to make CDI aware of it; but how? I tried various combinations of `@Named`, `@Default`, `@Model`, `@Singleton`, `@Stateless` and many resources such as questions and blog articles have they own interpretation of them.

What are the correct, plain CDI annotation to use to make this injection work in Jersey/Glassfish?

Comment: What version of glassfish?

Comment: @JohnAment Glassfish 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it seems that you did not put beans.xml file into your application. With Glassfish 4 (generally with Java EE 7) this file is not required, however, if you omit it, only beans annotated with scope annotations are considered. Therefore, as DefaultBookDAO is not marked by any annotation, it is not considered by CDI as a candidate for injection.

You have 2 options to fix it and make CDI mechanism consider DefaultBookDAO:

- put `@Dependent` annotation on DefaultBookDAO class - this will not change its scope, as `@Dependent` is the default scope, but will make CDI to consider this class
- create beans.xml file in either META-INF or WEB-INF (for web apps) with the value of `bean-discovery-mode="all"`

In my opinion, the first option is cleaner - you may easily separate code which can be injected and which cannot. But if you want to increase productivity by omitting unnecessary annotations, go with the second option. It is more complicated, but you have to do it only once per module.

Please see [this oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/default_cdi_enablement_in_java) about beans.xml in Java EE 7 and the default behavior if it is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a service you can annotate your `DefaultBookDAO` with `@Stateless`.

Then you need an additional class implementing the `AbstractBinder` class.

It should look like this for your case:

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

public class MyApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(DefaultBookDAO.class).to(BookDAO.class);
    }
}
```

You have to register this class in the class where you extend `ResourceConfig` like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/bookstore")
public class BookStore extends ResourceConfig {
    public BookStore() {
        register(new MyApplicationBinder());
        this.packages("my.bookstore.resource");
    }
}
```

Then the `@Inject` should work.

**See also:**

- [Jersey docs: Chapter 22. Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)
- [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0)

Comment: Do I really need a binder? Shouldn't Jersey look for implementations of `BookDAO` automatically to inject?

Comment: The error message `Unsatisfied dependencies for type BookDAO with qualifiers @Default` gives hint that CDI is used as a dependency injection mechanism. Your advice is related to HK2 mechanism, which is evidently also supported by Jersey, but is not specified in Java EE standards and is not used in standard setup of recent Glassfish v4.