# Rest Filter: registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, java-ee-6

I am getting an error:

> A provider com.xyx.in.astra.aqr.security.application.requestFilter.UniversalSessionManagerFilter
> registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime.
> Due to constraint configuration problems the provider
> com.xyx.in.astra.aqr.security.application.requestFilter.UniversalSessionManagerFilter will be ignored.

Note:

1. This UniversalSessionManagerFilter filter is in an external jar file which is in the server classpath
2. I am using `@Provider` annotation on the filter and `@Priority` annotation to define priority
3. This is a rest server filter

Comment: Jersey 2 and Jersey 1 use different ContainerRequestFilters. Jersey 2 uses a standard JAX-RS interface, while Jersey 1 uses an implementation specific one. They have different packing and slightly different contract. You need to make sure you are using the correct one for the version of Jersey you are using

Answer (score 7):

This has been reported as an issue in Jersey. See Jersey issue [#3700](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3700).

With Jersey 2.26 the warning message is triggered if you register an instantiated resource object directly on a `ResourceConfig`. However, the warning is intentional.

You can register a class instead of an instance. Or you can configure the resource via an [`AbstractBinder`](http://javaarm.com/file/glassfish/jersey/doc/userguide/Jersey-2.26-User-Guide.htm#d0e17032) and a [`Feature`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29275727/9768744).

If the warning actually originates from a third-party library registering a *resource* instance on a `ResourceConfig`, you can work around it by suppressing log messages from the `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers` logger as recommended in the [Jersey ticket](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3700).