# Jersey constructor with parameters

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, jersey, dao

I want to use a DAO in my RESTful service developed with Jersey, so the DAO implementation should be injected via the constructor of the service:

```
@Path("eventscheduler)
public class EventSchedulerService {
    private IEventSchedulerDao dao;

    public EventSchedulerService(IEventSchedulerDao dao) { this.dao = dao; }
}
```

However, I know Jersey expects a default constructor to setup everything correctly. I have been trying to figure out how to do this for a while but surprisingly this seems to be an uncommon case, I wonder how people inject DAOs into their services, or deal with injection in general at all.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Jersey 2, it uses [HK2](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b05/) as it's DI framework. All resource classes go through the DI lifecycle when they are constructed. And constructor injection is not a problem.

The most basic way (with Jersey) to make an arbitrary object injectable, is to bind in an `AbstractBinder`

```
public class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(EventSchedudlerDaoImpl.class).to(EventSchedulerDao.class);
    }
}
```

Then register the binder with Jersey

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(new Binder());
    }
}
```

Then you just need to declare the injection point by adding `@Inject` on top of the constructor.

```
@Inject
public EventSchedulerService(EventSchedulerDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}
```

As far as the binder implementation, the binding syntax basically reads as

```
bind( Implementation ).to( Contract ).in( Scope );
```

The `bind` method can take an instance or it can take a class. When you provide an instance, the Scope is automatically Singleton.

The `to` method specifies the advertised contract, which is the type that can be declared at the injection point. In this case, only the interface `EventSchedulerDao` can be used for the injection point. If you don't have an interface you can just do

```
bindAsContract(EventSchedulerDao.class)
```

assuming `EventSchedulerDao` is the implementation class.

The scopes available are `PerLookup`, `RequestScoped` and `Singleton`. If not specified, the default scope will be `PerLookup`, meaning a new instance of the service will be created for each injection point. You should already know what `Singleton` means. `RequestScoped` means that a new instance will be created for each request, which may not be the same as `PerLookup`, as the service may be injected at multiple points through out the request lifeclyle.

**See Also:**

- [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16216759/2587435)
- [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)
- [hk2](/questions/tagged/hk2) tagged questions. Alot of them are Jersey related.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but I have done as you specified in your really helpful answer but I am getting multiple exceptions when performing a request: `org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl` seems to be the root one. I created the binder and jersey config classes in separate files. Could this be it?

Comment: Did you already have  ResourceConfig before, or are you using web.xml? If you are using web.xml, you might want to look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29275727/2587435)

Comment: Yes that was it. However, it seems the DAO is not being injected because I am getting a null pointer exception. Do you have any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: The only thing I can think is you are binding incorrectly. But you are not getting the exception anymore? If you are not getting the exception, it _should_ work. How are you doing your binding?

Comment: The service is being called now. But the dao member in the service is null, so the injection is not working. I am not getting the exeption I was getting before, this one is different.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. I think you should change your answer. Instead of having the inject annotation in the constructor, it should be in the DAO member instead and get rid of the constructor.

Comment: Construction injection should work without a problem. Field injection is also an option. But the constructor injection should work. Dumb question but when using constructor injection, do you initialize the field in the constructor? Personally I prefer construction injection as it's easier to unit test. You should try to get that working. I use it all the time, so I don't know what you are doing differently, why it isn't working for you.

Comment: You're right, I was dumb and removed the assignment line because your original answer omitted it in the constructor. But it works both ways, either annotating the member or annotating the constructor. I guess it's a matter of taste?

Comment: By the way, do you mind if I ask you about something you said in the last block of your answer? Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113731/discussion-between-dabadaba-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 1):

You must annotate the class constructor (or the property itself) with `javax.inject.Inject`.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

class EventSchedulerResource {
  private final IEventSchedulerDao dao;

  @Inject
  public EventSchedulerResource(IEventSchedulerDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  // ...

}
```

If the `IEventScheduler` is an interface you must create a configuration class class that extends `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` and register the binding of interface to a concrete implementation with `bind(EventSchedulerDaoImpl.class).to(IEventScheduler.class)` (See here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html chapter 23.1)

Comment: New location for chapter 23.1:  https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/ioc.html