# JerseyTest unsatisfied dependency (Dependency Injection)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, jersey

I need to test my RESTful service and I thought the most appropriate way to do it would be using the [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) since I am already using Jersey for my service.

However, when running a simple test I am getting a `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` because the implementation of the DAO I am using in the service is not found (it's being set via DI). This error used to happen to me everytime I modified my `pom.xml` Maven configuration file, mostly when adding or removing dependencies. Supposedly, the IDE I'm using, IntelliJ IDEA is supposed to regenerate the artifacts automatically, but for me to avoid this dependency failure I needed to remove the *old* artifact from the Tomcat server deployment options as well as from the project structure, and add it again.

The problem here is that the test framework is using a separate server, as the documentation said. I am using the following one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know how to solve the dependency issue if I am using a different server.

The top error message in the exception stack says:

> org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no
>   object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl

Any ideas?

**Edit.** I managed to patch it with a dirty solution.

First, let me show you how I was injecting the DAO:

```
// Binder.java
public class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(TournamentDao.class).to(ITournamentDao.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}

// DependencyInjectionFeature.java
@Provider
public class DependencyInjectionFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new Binder());
        return true;
    }
}

// EventSchedulerService.java
@Path("eventscheduler")
public class EventSchedulerService {
    private ITournamentDao dao;

    @Inject
    public EventSchedulerService(ITournamentDao tournamentDao) {
        dao = tournamentDao;
    }
}
```

The web configuration file `web.xml` scans the package where these classes are placed (the package has the same name than the one where the test exists) and perform the dependency injection since it finds the `@Provider` annotation.

To patch my issue I did the exact same thing in the test class:

```
public class EventSchedulerServiceTest extends JerseyTest {
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(EventSchedulerService.class);
        config.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(TournamentDao.class).to(ITournamentDao.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
        return config;
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a bad idea because now I have duplicate code; but it did the trick. I'd like to know how to make the test server to use the service configuration correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember from a previous discussion [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613409/2587435), you had the problem of not using a `ResourceConfig` to configure your main application. You we instead using web.xml.

The reason you are using a `Feature` annotated with `@Provider` is that you we're using package scanning in your web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>your.packages.to.scan</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The package scan picked up the `@Provider` on the `Feature`, and automatically registers it. This provider is what is used to register the `Binder`, which is what configured the dependency injection.

As mentioned, a Jersey application can be configured in a `ResourceConfig` or in a web.xml. Anything jersey configuration you can do in the web.xml, you can also do in the `ResourceConfig`. There are a bunch of different ways you can register components with the `ResourceConfig`

- You can just call `register`

  ```
  config.register(new DependencyInjectionFeature());
  ```
- You can also package scan, the same way you are doing in the web.xml, by calling `packages`

  ```
  config.packages("your.packages.to.scan");
  ```
- You should also look at your implementation of the `Binder` class. It extends `AbstractBinder`. The look at how you are currently configuring the DI in the test

  ```
  config.register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
         ...
      }
  });
  ```

  You are registering an `AbstractBinder` instance. So you know that calling you can register the DI configuration calling `register` on the `ResourceConfig`, so you could instead of registering a different binder, just register an instance of the `Binder` class

  ```
  config.register(new Binder());
  ```

So you have some options.

Comment: I understand now. So basically I need to configure the server used in the test the same way than the "main" one. So for each `@Provider` I have I just need to just `register()` it? For example, I have custom exception mappers. But I am having trouble with some exceptions, how should I configure it in order to reach the same behaviour?

Comment: Same thing. You can register the mapper the same way; package scanning or explicit registration with the `register` method

Comment: But I don't have a mapper for 404 errors. I think it's built in as default Jersey behaviour. When you throw a `NotFoundException()` it's automatically generating a 404 response. But in my test it's responding with code 500.

Comment: This is an unrelated topic for this post. Please continue discussion in other post