# No server side events returned

Tags: java, jersey

i am trying to implement server side events.
I have very simple resource exposed by a RESTful web service with Jersey/Grizzly. I try to broadcast the events with the SseBroadcaster. An event is created, whenever a data item comes in and is added to an internal list. A client should open a connection to the URL /events to receive the events.

```
@Path("sensordataelements")
public class SensorDataResource {

    private SseBroadcaster broadcaster = new SseBroadcaster();

    @GET
    @Path("events")
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        broadcaster.add(eventOutput);
        return eventOutput;
    }
    @POST
    @Path("/addraw")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addRawSensorData(String elementBody) {
        ... data processing stuff ...
        cList.add(
                new SensorDataElement.SensorDataElementBuilder().id()
                .sensorReading(tmpValue)
                .build()
                );
        OutboundEvent evt = new OutboundEvent.Builder()
                .data(Float.class, Float.valueOf(tmpValue))
                .build();
        broadcaster.broadcast(evt);

        return Response.status(201).build();
    }
...
```

I tried to connect with

> curl -v http://localhost:8080/sensordataapp/sensordataelements/events

The connection is fine, but i do not get any events. I looked at some examples, but got the impression that this should work. What did i miss?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure cURL supports SSE? Have you tried with a different client that supports SSE, like the Jersey client, or Javascript? Also after a client is connected, someone needs to send a post request to actually send a message to the subscribing client.

Comment: Well, there are some examples showing curl beeing used. The POST method is called on a regular basis. So this sould be fine. Could there be a problem with the broadcaster class?

Comment: Make sure the resource class is a singleton. Otherwise a new one is created for each request, which means a new broadcaster is created for each request. Or if you want to keep the default behavior of a new resource created for each request. you should _inject_ a singleton instance of the broadcaster, instead of instantiating it yourself

Comment: You can add `@Singleton` on top of the resource class. That will make it a singleton

Comment: Declaring Singleton did the trick :) Thanks! Would you like to post this as an answer, so the question is marked as "solved"? Could you point me to a source where i can understand how to inject as a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a new instance of the resource class is created for each request. This means that a new broadcaster is created for each request, which isn't what you want. If you want to make the resource class a Singleton, you can simply annotate the class with `@Singleton`

```
@Singleton
@Path("sensordataelements")
public class SensorDataResource {
     ...
}
```

Now, only one instance of the resource class will be created for the entire application, and it will be shared for all requests.

The other option, is if you *inject* the broadcaster, instead of instantiating it yourself, you can inject it as a Singleton. Whether or not the resource class is a singleton or not, it will still get injected the same broadcaster instance. To do that, you can do something like the following in your `ResourceConfig` subclass

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(new SseBroadcaster()).to(SseBroadcaster.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your resource class, just inject it

```
@Path("sensordataelements")
public class SensorDataResource {

    @Inject
    private SseBroadcaster broadcaster;
```

**See also:**

- [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16216759/2587435)