# Java EntityManager null with @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, entitymanager, jta

I'm using Wildfly 10, Jersey, and injecting dependencies with @Inject. I have DAO and Service interfaces with their implementations declared in a CustomBinder. The injections work well, but the **EntityManager** is injected **null** with the **@PersistenceContext** annotation. I'm using MySQL and the datasource test-connection is working.

**API Rest class**

```
@Path("/account")
public class CuentaServiceRS {

    @Inject
    private ICuentaService cuentaService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Cuenta getCuenta() {
        return cuentaService.getCuentas().get(0);       
    }

}
```

The **implementation** of **ICuentaService**

```
@Stateless
public class CuentaServiceImpl implements ICuentaService {

    @Inject
    private ICuentaDAO cuentaDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Cuenta> getCuentas() {
        List<Cuenta> cuentas = cuentaDAO.getAllCuentas();
        cuentas;
    }

}
```

The **implementation** of **CuentaDAO**

```
@Stateless
public class CuentaDAOImpl implements ICuentaDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "altitudePU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Cuenta> getAllCuentas() {
        CriteriaQuery<Cuenta> cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Cuenta.class);

        /...

        return resultlist;
    }

}
```

My persistence-unit in **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="altitudePU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/AltitudePU</jta-data-source>
    <class>ar.com.olx.domain.Cuenta</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>    
</persistence-unit>
```

The servlet configured on **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>altitudeservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>ar.com.villat.bind.ApplicationJaxRS</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My custom **AplicationJaxRS** which extendes from ResourceConfig

```
public class ApplicationJaxRS extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationJaxRS(){
        register(new CustomBinder());
        packages(true, "ar.com.olx");
    }

}
```

The **CustomBinder**

```
public class CustomBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(CuentaServiceImpl.class).to(ICuentaService.class);
        bind(CuentaDAOImpl.class).to(ICuentaDAO.class);
    }

}
```

And finally, my **pom.xml** dependencies related to this post

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you need more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a full stack JavaEE server you can simplify this a lot.

If you have not added a MySQL datasource to WildFly then you can do it like this:

### WildFly Datasource Setup

1. Create a file called `deploy-mysql-ds.cli` with the following content:

   ```
   # Execute offline
   embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml

   deploy $HOME/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar

   # Add the application datasource
   data-source add \
       --name=AltitudeDS \
       --driver-name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar \
       --connection-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/altitudeDB \
       --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/AltitudePU \
       --user-name=$USER_NAME \
       --password=$PASSWORD
   ```
2. Replace `$HOME`, `$USER_NAME` and `$PASSWORD` with real values
3. Configure the data source in Wildfly by executing it like:

   ```
   $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file="deploy-mysql-ds.cli"
   ```

You only need to do this once.

Note that the `--jndi-name` matches the `<jta-data-source>...</jta-data-source>` in 
your persistence.xml file.

You do not need the mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar in your maven dependencies because it has been added to the server directly. There are other solutions that involve adding the jar as a "module"
but I find this way to be much simpler.

### Amend Application

Amend your application as follows:

1. Remove all the redundant dependencies:

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax</groupId>
           <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
           <version>7.0</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
           <version>3.4</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
2. Remove the `AplicationJaxRS` and `CustomBinder` classes and add a `JAXRSConfiguration` class:

   ```
   /**
    * Configures a JAX-RS endpoint
    */
   @ApplicationPath("resources")
   public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {
   }
   ```
3. Remove the `altitudeservlet` from the web.xml. If that is the only thing in it then completely remove the whole file.

### Test it

You should be able to deploy this web application and access it from:

```
http://localhost:8080/altitude-webapp/resources/account
```

where `altitude-webapp` is the name of your WAR file.

Comment: Hi Steve, two questions: what should I put on JAXRSConfiguration? I'm using Jersey, that's why I have a CustomBinder by now; If I remove "altitudeservlet", how should I do to configure the POJOMapping? Thank you

Comment: Forget Jersey for now and get something up and running. We can address that later

Comment: Everything is working now! Just out of curiosity, I have to leave JAXRSConfiguration empty, or is it useful for some configurations? Thanks

Comment: This class is often empty. The best place to find out more about it is in §2 of the [JAX-RS 2.0 Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html)