# Jersey Configuration Not identifying service and dao classes

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jersey

This is my jersey config class

```
@ApplicationPath("services")
    public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig{
    public JerseyApplication() {

            packages("com.ems");

            register(EmployeeService.class);
        }
    }
```

Here `autowiring` of `employeeService` is giving a null pointer exception

```
@Path("/ems")
@Component
public class EmployeeRestController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GET
    @Path("/employees")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employeeService.getEmployees();
    }
}
```

I have tried everything 
In my `employeeServiceImpl` I have @service annotation 
Still, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

To configure the dependency injection using the built in DI framework (HK2), you should use an `AbstractBinder`, as mentioned in some answers in [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16216759/2587435).

```
@ApplicationPath("services")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {

        packages("com.ems");

        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(EmployeeService.class)
                        .to(EmployeeService.class)
                        .in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Secondly, you do not use the `@Autowired` annotation. This annotation is specifically for Spring. For standard injection with Jersey, just use the `@Inject` annotation. Also remove the `@Component` annotation, as this is also for Spring.

As an aside, if you *do* want to integrate Spring with Jersey, you should read [Why and How to Use Spring With Jersey](https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/10/19/why-use-spring-with-jersey.html). It will break down what you need to understand about integrating the two frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You should register Controller not Service class.
[Sample](https://github.com/cassiomolin/jersey-jwt-springsecurity/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cassiomolin/example/common/api/config/JerseyConfig.java)

```
@ApplicationPath("services")
    public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig{
    public JerseyApplication() {

            packages("com.ems");

            register(EmployeeRestController.class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know anything about Injection ? beacuse the problem is it is not performing injection of dependencies