# How can I pass a shared object to a ResourceConfig in Jetty?

Tags: jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am writing a small embedded Jetty web server, but I have a shared object that has an expensive construction and I don't want each single request to the servlet to have to rebuild this object. Unfortunately the way I add a resource in Jetty is through the `ResourceConfig` constructor, but this does not allow me to do anything beyond adding the class name:

```
 // instantiate this expensive object
 MyExpensiveSharedObjectClass myExpensiveSharedObject = new MyExpensiveSharedObjectClass();
 String result = myExpensiveSharedObject.search("alpha");

 // set up the service
 final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(MyService.class);
```

Then `MyService.java` contains your standard declarations such as:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/doSomething")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String doSomething() {
        // do stuff with myExpensiveSharedObject....except how do I get to it??
        // String result = myExpensiveSharedObject.search("alpha");
```

What I want ideally is a way that each time a request comes into `/doSomething`, I can perform methods on the `myExpensiveSharedObject` object that I've created earlier.

I imagine this is quite simple but I can't find a simple method of accomplishing this.

Alternatively - is there a way to have some form of shared memory space within the Jetty servlet? I noticed that every single request seems to instantiate a new instance of the servlet, so I can't, for example, build up a shared memory map within the object that can be reused by all instances of the class. I am sure this is possible but I can't figure out how to do it.

Basically, I'm just trying to find a way to have an object that is expensive to construct, something that would be ideal within a constructor method or passed into the servlet itself, but within the context of these servlets, constructors are called every single request, so I can't go that route.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running into jersey issues, not jetty ones (but you may also be running into issues with both!).  See if [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0) helps you understand how to do inject dependencies into your resource classes.  If so, then you should be able to do

```
bind(myExpensiveSharedObject).to(MyExpensiveSharedObjectClass.class)
```

in an AbstractBinder implementation, which you can then register with jersey's `ResourceConfig` by doing

```
resourceConfig.register(binder)
```

Comment: Ha yeah I'm totally lost... that example points to lots of XML configuration (which I don't have). Do you know of any simple full examples for embedded jetty servers?

Comment: The XML is, I believe, just for setting up a ResourceConfig via servlet config mechanisms.  Since you're doing so programmatically you should be able to ignore that part, create an `AbstractBinder` subclass that binds your expensive object, and register it with the `resourceConfig`.  The best full example for jetty/jersey is probably the dropwizard source, but I wouldn't say it's simple.